# How to combine two nullable boolean fields in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these fields :

```
 ISNULL(
    dbo.Features.TheifAlarm,
    0
) AS ExtraTheifAlarm,
 ISNULL(
    dbo.Features.FireAlarm,
    0
) AS ExtraFireAlarm,
```

`dbo.Features.TheifAlarm` and `dbo.Features.FireAlarm` are nullable `bits`. But I'm using EntityFramework and they are nullable `boolean` in my model. I want to combine them with `OR`.

This is my attempt :

```
     ISNULL(
        dbo.Features.TheifAlarm,
        0
    )
OR
     ISNULL(
        dbo.Features.FireAlarm,
        0
    )
```

But it didn't work, how can I combine these two columns? Thanks in advance

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry, they are bits. I'm updating my question.

Comment: ISNULL(
        dbo.Features.TheifAlarm,
        0
    )=1 OR ...

Comment: @Serg How does it combine these fields? I couldn't understand. Thanks.

Comment: why not use `coalesce` here `coalesce(dbo.Features.TheifAlarm, dbo.Features.FireAlarm) =1`

Comment: Show the query. I assume you want combine them in WHERE clause as you use OR

Comment: @crai Because `COALESCE` will return with 0 when `TheifAlarm = 0` and `FireAlarm = 1` which in this case is not the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 'combine' two fields you can use [bitwise operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx).

In your case (in the SELECT list):

```
SELECT (ISNULL(col1, 0) | ISNULL(col2, 0)) AS combinedCol FROM ...
```

Or as a WHERE condition:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (ISNULL(col1, 0) = 1 OR ISNULL(col2, 0) = 1)
```

Actually you don't even need the ISNULL() in the WHERE condition (`col1 = 1` evaluates to FALSE (ok, NULL, but treated as FALSE) when col1 is null):

```
SELECT ... WHERE (col1 = 1 OR col2 = 1)
```

Edit: Just to add some alternatives:

Simple addition

```
SELECT IIF((ISNULL(col1, 0) + ISNULL(col2, 0)) > 0, 1, 0)
```

CASE..WHEN  structure (as iamdave mentioned)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE IIF(col2 = 1, 1, 0) END
```

Another CASE..WHEN

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (col1 = 1 OR col2 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

or with IIF

```
SELECT IIF(col1 = 1 OR col2 = 1), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, can the first option work with nullable types?

Comment: ISNULL(something, 0) will return 0 when 'something' is null. so yes, it works with nullables when ISNULL or COALESCE is present.

Comment: @jason There, now you can choose. Check the execution plans ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to return a `true` if either field is `true`?

If so, you can check for both with a `case`:

```
select case when ISNULL(dbo.Features.TheifAlarm,0) = 0  -- If the first is False
            then ISNULL(dbo.Features.FireAlarm,0)       -- Return the value of the second
            else 1                                      -- Otherwise return True
            end as EitherAlarmCheck
```

If you are looking to filter your dataset for one of these values being `True`, you can use an `OR` in your `where` clause:

```
select Cols
from Table
where ISNULL(dbo.Features.TheifAlarm,0) = 1
   or ISNULL(dbo.Features.FireAlarm,0) = 1
```